# Loop through to find and print respective values from one workbook to the active workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie to VBA so please be patient.
I have a workbook saved on my computer with the following data:

```
Name    Value
A            6
B            10
C            13
D            9
E            10
F            17
G            6
H            6
```

In my active workbook, I have the following data:

```
A
C
B
D
E
```

I need to loop through the first workbook and print the respective values in my current workbook.
Here is what I was able to do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Group As Range, Mat As Range
    Dim CurCell_1 As Range, CurCell_2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select the file")
    If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb1 = app.Workbooks.Open(Ret1)
    Set wb2 = app.ActiveWorkbook


    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each Group In ws1.Range("A2:A9")
        Set CurCell_2 = ws2.Range("B2:B6")
        For Each Mat In ws1.Range("B2:B9")
            Set CurCell_1 = ws1.Cells(Mat.Row, Group.Column)
            If Not IsEmpty(CurCell_1) Then
                CurCell_2.Value = CurCell_1.Value
                Set CurCell_2 = CurCell_2.Offset(1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Really not sure about the range(s).

Comment: `I am newbie to VBA so please be patient.` Fair enough But see this. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I have voted this question to be closed. If you update your question with the code that you tried then I will retract my vote :)

Comment: Ok I have retracted my vote. Quick question. Why do you want to use VBA? You can use `Vlookup` formula to achieve what you want...

Comment: I am newbie to StackOverFlow as well :(

Comment: That's the problem. Sort of a task given at school. Need to use loop.

Comment: That's ok. We all were newbies at one point or the other ;) See my last comment.

Comment: Ok. looking at the code now... one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve what you want. Here are 3 ways...

**WAY 1 (Using `.Find`)**

You might want to see [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) as well.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Group As Range, Mat As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim Ret

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select the file")

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Ret)
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook


    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws2
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            Set aCell = ws1.Columns(1).Find(What:=.Range("A" & i).Value, _
                                                         LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                         MatchCase:=False, _
                                                         SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    wb1.Close (False)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**WAY 2 (Using `Loops`)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Group As Range, Mat As Range
    Dim lRowWs1 As Long, lRoWws2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Ret

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select the file")

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Ret)
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook


    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet38")

    With ws2
        lRoWws2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lRowWs1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRoWws2
            For j = 1 To lRowWs1
                If .Range("A" & i).Value = ws1.Range("A" & j).Value Then
                    .Range("B" & i).Value = ws1.Range("B" & j).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

    wb1.Close (False)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**WAY 3 (Using `Vlookup` Formula in Code)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Group As Range, Mat As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim FName As String
    Dim Ret

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
    , "Please select the file")

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Ret)
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

    FName = wb1.Name

    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet38")

    With ws2
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,[" & FName & "]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)"
        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Value = .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Value
    End With

    wb1.Close (False)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Dude. Works like a breeze. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Kool :) I hope you won't just copy paste the code but actually understand how it works.. :)